# How trigger a event button inside a Material Dialog Component?

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have one material dialog component and i'm trying to open it and click in the "confirm" button there is inside my modal, but i'm getting this error:

> TypeError: confirmButton is null in
> http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/main.js (line 20740)

I tried:

```
it('should open the modal and click in the confirm button', () => {
    spyOn(component.dialog,'open').and.callThrough();
    component.openDialog();
    const confirmButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#dialog-confirm-button'));
    confirmButton.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    // my expect will be there later
});
```

This is my dialog:

```
<div>
  <div mat-dialog-content>
    Opened dialog
  </div>
  <div mat-dialog-actions align="center">
    <button id="dialog-confirm-button" [mat-dialog-close]="true" mat-flat-button
      color="accent">Confirm</button>
    <button id="dialog-cancel-button" [mat-dialog-close]="false" mat-flat-button color="primary">
      Cancel
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my `openDialog()` function:

```
openDialog(): Observable<boolean> {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
}
```

Comment: In your test, after `component.openDialog();`, try adding a `fixture.detectChanges();` to detect the changes of what goes on in `openDialog` and actually make the dialog open.

Comment: @AliF50 i tried with `detectChanges()` and `whenStable()`, but in both case i'm receiving null in my button

Comment: @veroneseComS did you solved this problem?

Comment: @obaram yes but i don't remember how... srry